# HTML displaying values in JavaScript "data"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

The following JavaScript code is used to display table data into a chart.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#container').highcharts({
                data: {
                    table: 'datatable'
                },
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Results'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    allowDecimals: false,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Units'
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                            this.point.y + ' ' + this.point.name.toLowerCase();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

HTML code which holds data:

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<table id="datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Jane</th>
            <th>John</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Apples</th>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Pears</th>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I also have the following  values in my HTML:

```
<div id="name"> </div>
<div id="age"></div>
```

"name" and "age" hold different values. How can I implement the  values into the chart instead of the data: (Jane, John, Apples,Pears). Is this possible?

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-parsed/

That is kind of how my chart is displaying atm. Can I put "name" and "age" on the chart instead?

Comment: What you have inside the name/age, also tables?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague but I'll try my best to help. I'm sure we all could provide a better answer if more information was provided such as:

**What is the data that you want to show on the chart?**

What is the value you want measured? For example, are you measuring years?

Are you measuring different elements of the same person or the same elements for different people?

I'm assuming when you stated that you want to display "name" and "age" on the chart instead of what's provided in the example, you want to display names with the age being the measuring value. If that's the case then here's what I came up with.

[**JSFiddle:** Javascript HighChart Example with Age as Measuring Value](http://jsfiddle.net/rocketrisa/1s30hzx0/)

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Age of Major Life Events'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Created By: <a href="http://www.rocketrisa.com">Rocket Risa</a>'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['John', 'Jane', 'Jessica', 'Jordan', 'Jeri'],
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Age (years)',
                align: 'high'
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' years'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -40,
            y: 80,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
            shadow: true
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Teen',
            data: [15, 13, 18, 14, 17]
        }, {
            name: 'Young Adult',
            data: [23, 28, 21, 25, 27]
        }, {
            name: 'Middle Age 30+',
            data: [35, 46, 32, 64, 51]
        }]
    });
});
```